# keras: record layer-wise learning rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm implementing a simple CNN with Keras, and trying to set up layer-wise learning rate in Adam. I take a reference of [this tutorial](https://erikbrorson.github.io/2018/04/30/Adam-with-learning-rate-multipliers/). The revised Adam as shown below:

```
class Adam_lr_mult(Optimizer): 
    def __init__(self, lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,
                 epsilon=None, decay=0., amsgrad=False,
                 multipliers=None, debug_verbose=True,**kwargs):
        ...'''Omitted'''

        self.multipliers = multipliers
        self.layerwise_lr={}    # record layer-wise lr
        self.debug_verbose = debug_verbose

    @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
    def get_updates(self, loss, params):
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
        self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

        lr = self.lr
        if self.initial_decay > 0:
        lr *= (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                              K.dtype(self.decay))))

        t = K.cast(self.iterations, K.floatx()) + 1
        lr_t = lr * (K.sqrt(1. - K.pow(self.beta_2, t)) /
                     (1. - K.pow(self.beta_1, t)))

        ms = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
        vs = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
        if self.amsgrad:
            vhats = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
        else:
            vhats = [K.zeros(1) for _ in params]

        self.weights = [self.iterations] + ms + vs + vhats

        for p, g, m, v, vhat in zip(params, grads, ms, vs, vhats):

            # Learning rate multipliers
            if self.multipliers:
                multiplier = [mult for mult in self.multipliers if mult in p.name]
                if self.debug_verbose:
                    print('parameter: ',p.name)
            else:
                multiplier = None

            if multiplier:
                new_lr_t = lr_t * self.multipliers[multiplier[0]]
                self.layerwise_lr[multiplier[0]] = K.get_value(new_lr_t)

                if self.debug_verbose:
                    print('Setting {} to learning rate : {}'.format(multiplier[0], new_lr_t))
                    print('learning rate:',K.get_value(new_lr_t))
                    print('Dict:',self.layerwise_lr)
                    print('\n')
            else:
                new_lr_t = lr_t
                self.layerwise_lr[p.name.split('/')[0]] = K.get_value(new_lr_t)

                if self.debug_verbose:
                    print('No change in learning rate : {}'.format(p.name))
                    print('learning rate:',K.get_value(new_lr_t))
                    print('Dict:',self.layerwise_lr)
                    print('\n')

            ...'''Omitted'''

        print(***__Hello__***)
        return self.updates
```

Besides, I use ReduceLROnPlateau and CSVLogger callback function to record learning rate. In order to record more information about layer-wise learning rate, I also revise ReduceLROnPlateau:

```
class ReduceLROnPlateau_lr_mult(Callback):
    def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=10,
             verbose=0, mode='auto', min_delta=1e-4, cooldown=0, min_lr=0,
             **kwargs):
        ...'''Omitted'''

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        logs['lr'] = K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)
        logs.update(self.model.optimizer.layerwise_lr) # only add this line
        ...'''Omitted'''
```

In order to test revised Adam and ReduceLROnPlateau function, I use MNIST dataset and build a simple CNN with only 4 convolution layers, 4 batch_normalization layers and 1 dense layer, the code and result as shown below:

```
# Learning multiplier
lr_multipliers = {}
lr_multipliers['conv2d_1'] = 0.8
lr_multipliers['batch_normalization_1'] = 0.8
lr_multipliers['conv2d_2'] = 0.6
lr_multipliers['conv2d_3'] = 0.4
lr_multipliers['conv2d_4'] = 0.2

# Adam with layer-wise lr
adam_lr_mult = Adam_lr_mult(multipliers=lr_multipliers)

# ReduceLROnPlateau with layer-wise lr dict
lr_reducer_mult = ReduceLROnPlateau_lr_mult(monitor='val_loss',factor=np.sqrt(0.1), 
                      cooldown=0, patience=5, min_lr=0.00001, mode='auto', verbose=1)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_lr_mult, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(...,verbose=2,
             callbacks=[lr_reducer_mult, early_stopper, csv_logger, ...])
```

the result shows:

```
...'''Omitted'''
parameter:  batch_normalization_4/beta:0
No change in learning rate : batch_normalization_4/beta:0
learning rate: 0.00031623512
Dict: {'conv2d_1': 0.00025298807, 'batch_normalization_1': 0.00025298807,...}

parameter:  dense_1/kernel:0
No change in learning rate : dense_1/kernel:0
learning rate: 0.00031623512
Dict: {'conv2d_1': 0.00025298807, 'batch_normalization_1': 0.00025298807,...}

parameter:  dense_1/bias:0
No change in learning rate : dense_1/bias:0
learning rate: 0.00031623512
Dict: {'conv2d_1': 0.00025298807, 'batch_normalization_1': 0.00025298807,...}

***__Hello__***
Train on 48000 samples, validate on 12000 samples
Epoch 1/100
 - 4s - loss: 0.4517 - acc: 0.9098 - val_loss: 0.2027 - val_acc: 0.9572
Epoch 2/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.1029 - acc: 0.9827 - val_loss: 0.1374 - val_acc: 0.9718
Epoch 3/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0739 - acc: 0.9905 - val_loss: 0.0929 - val_acc: 0.9833
Epoch 4/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0604 - acc: 0.9939 - val_loss: 0.0815 - val_acc: 0.9865
Epoch 5/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0513 - acc: 0.9959 - val_loss: 0.0785 - val_acc: 0.9864
Epoch 6/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0448 - acc: 0.9979 - val_loss: 0.1081 - val_acc: 0.9759
Epoch 7/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0405 - acc: 0.9984 - val_loss: 0.0752 - val_acc: 0.9864
Epoch 8/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0368 - acc: 0.9990 - val_loss: 0.1382 - val_acc: 0.9666
Epoch 9/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0337 - acc: 0.9996 - val_loss: 0.0659 - val_acc: 0.9890
Epoch 10/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0314 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.0746 - val_acc: 0.9860
...

Epoch 25/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0177 - acc: 0.9991 - val_loss: 0.1212 - val_acc: 0.9731

Epoch 00025: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.00031622778103685084.
Epoch 26/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0155 - acc: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.0446 - val_acc: 0.9915
Epoch 27/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0146 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0422 - val_acc: 0.9926
```

My question:

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, `logs['lr']` changes in [CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77x5g.jpg) but the `dictionary "layerwise_lr"` doesn't. In order to find out the problem, I add a line
`print(***__Hello__***)` in Adam and it only appear one time. Which makes me confused, the information about setting learning rate only appeared before first epoch and never appear again. Could anybody give me some suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Did you find any answer to solve this problem? I have a same problem.